# mod_rewrite rule move specific GET parameter to the end

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I hope someone can help me out with this.

I need to turn this:

```
/page/?lang=en&param1=x&param2=y&param3=z
```

into this:

```
/page/?param1=x&param2=y&param3=z&lang=en
```

where param1, param2 & param3 can be any number of parameters with arbitrary names and lang can have any value consisting of 2 letters.

I'm running a WP website with some plugins that don't work properly when the lang parameter is added before the others. However, the WPML multilanguage plugin automatically moves the lang parameter to the beginning of the query string when you use the language switcher at the top of the page...

Comment: why would order make any difference. thats very odd behavior.

Comment: I know, that shouldn't make any difference. First I thought it simply doesn't work when WPML is enabled but after trying a lot of different solutions I discovered that this is how I could get it to work...

Comment: You need to troubleshoot the shady plugin instead of rearranging the url params. This is not a good sign.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)lang=en&(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1%2&lang=en
```

Should work, I think, though it looks line noise-ish enough to be Perl.

Comment: That's vague. It works for me: `http://127.0.0.1/test/move-parameter/?test=1&lang=en&something=0` gets me `test=1&something=0&lang=en`, and so does `http://127.0.0.1/test/move-parameter/?lang=en&test=1&something=0`. Have you looked at what's in $_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]?